# Is there a way to show/hide toggle with a image in the same div that shows and hides

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am working on showing and hide a div contain text to be able to see the background image behind.  I was helped very on getting my div to move just a little and keep my div visible on the side

```
$("#welcome").toggle(
   function() {
    var left = $(this).outerWidth() - 10 + "px";

    $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "+=" + left }, 500);
  $(this).onClick() },
   function() {
    var left = $(this).outerWidth() - 10 + "px";

    $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + left }, 500);
   }
 );
```

Now i want my image in the html to change form HIDE to show...

```
<div id="welcomepicture"> 
<div id="welcome">
 Welcome  some really meaningful text here!

  <p class="arrowfull"><a href="#"> <img class="img-swap"  src="http://housing.ucsc.edu/guide/css/images/hide_off.png" alt="Click to view full image" title="Click to view full image" height="42" width="17"> </a></p>
```

I am not sure if in the javascript if I put .onClick image swap?  or do I write a new var?
New to jquery and javascript, thanks for your help

http://jsfiddle.net/BeccaAlley/UfsS8/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the source of the image in your toggle function.
The best way would be to put your show and your hide in one image and use background-position to move between them. That way you'll only load 1 image instead of 2.

```
$("#welcome").toggle(
    function() {
        var left = $(this).outerWidth() - 10 + "px";

        $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "+=" + left }, 500);
        $('.img-swap').attr('src','show.jpg');
    },
    function() {
        var left = $(this).outerWidth() - 10 + "px";

        $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + left }, 500);
        $('.img-swap').attr('src','hide.jpg');
    }
);
```

Comment: I think what I was doing wrong was not having .attr in my code, thanks Pedro for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the image to show when you click on the "Click to view full image" you can add the following code to the bottom of your js file:

```
$('.img-swap').click(function(){
    $('#imageID').show();
});
```

In this code you can change #imageID to the id of the id of the image that you would like to display. If you are using a class to reference the image instead of an id, then of course you would use a '.' instead of a '#'. Let me know if that helps or if you were looking for something a little different.